# Зацикливание кода

Tags: java

У меня задача чтобы когда в консоль вводили слово, программа проверяла является ли слово палиндромом и выводила true или false. Но нужно сделать так чтобы после первого введенного слова программа не завершалась и можно было дальше вводить слова. Максимум что у меня вышло это вводить сколько угодно раз слова, но программа проверяет только самое первое введенное.  Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public  class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Введите палиндром");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String x = scan.nextLine();
    String a = x;
    String reverse = new StringBuilder(a).reverse().toString();
    Boolean proverka = a.equals(reverse); 
    int h = 0 ;
    while(true) {
while(h==0 ) {
h++;    
    if (proverka) {
        System.out.println(proverka);   
    }
    
if(!proverka) {
    System.out.println(proverka);
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Чтобы было зацикливание кода, нужно этот самый код поместить в цикл. Вроде очевидно, не?

Comment: точно))) я исправил. Спасибо. Туплю сильно(